# Python dict get value fastest way

Tags: python

Is this the best way to get the value/key of `someID`.

I want to separate the keys and values I receive:

```
items={'someID': 2,}
for item in items:
    key = item
    print(key)
    value = items.get(item)
    print(value)
```

This works, but is this the correct/fastest way in Python 3.4?

Comment: Use  .items if you want both key and value.

Comment: What about `items.keys()` and `items.values()`?

Comment: "Correct" and "fast" depend on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the items() method to iterate over the keys and values.

```
d = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better is

```
for key, value in items.items():
   print (key)
   print (value)
```

Then you don't need getting values

Comment: `.iteritems()` does not exist in Python3. You should use `.items()` instead (which by the way returns an iterable as `.iteritems()` does in python2.7)